# Powershell - Create Document Library on All Sites or Sites in list

Tags: document-library, powershell

I'm looking to create multiple document libraries on a list of sites.

I've got most the pieces; I'm just having trouble combining them correctly. Here's the code for making the libraries. If I have 50+ sites(same collection) to make these same libraries on, how should I do that?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
    $siteColl = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://sitename/
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary 

$siteColl.Lists.Add("Library1","",$listTemplate) 
$siteColl.Lists.Add("Library2","",$listTemplate) 
$siteColl.Lists.Add("Library3","",$listTemplate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple list using the the following code by reading setting from xml file. You can specified the template as required

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

[xml]$config = Get-Content $directorypath"\Libraries.xml"

foreach($library in $config.libraries.library){
    $web = Get-SPWeb $library.web
    $template = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::($library.template)
    $web.Lists.Add($library.url,$library.description, $template);
    $web.Update();

}
```

Create an xml file called  **Libraries.xml** and copied the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <libraries>
      <library>
        <template>DocumentLibrary</template>
        <url>Control</url>
        <title>Document Library1</title>
        <description>This is a Control library</description>
        <web>www.contoso.com</web>
      </library>

      <library>
        <template>DocumentLibrary2</template>
        <url>Control</url>
        <title>DocumentLibrary2</title>
        <description>This is a Control library</description>
        <web>www.contoso.com</web>
      </library>
    </libraries>
```

For more info, you can have a look into the following post:
http://selingernetwork.com/blog/?p=53